# Why doesn't this recursive algorithm to find a node in a tree closest to a value K not work?

Tags: java

So if I'm given a value like 12 (which is the variable key), and I traverse the tree to find the node with the value closest to 12, this is the program I wrote.

```
public static int closest (Node<Integer, Person> n1, int smallest, int difference, int key, int key1) {
    while (n1 != null) {
        difference = key - n1.key;
        if (smallest == 0) {
            smallest = difference;
            key1 = n1.key;
        }
        else {
            if (difference < smallest) {
                smallest = difference;
                key1 = n1.key;
            }
        }
        closest(n1.rightChild, smallest, difference, key, key1);
        closest(n1.leftChild, smallest, difference, key, key1);
    }
    return key1;
}
```

From my debugger though, it appears that once the rightest Child is reached, that recursive call doesn't end and instead runs infinitely for some reason. So my tree from the root down the right subtree would be 6 -> 7 -> 8 -> 11, and once it reaches 11, it just stays at 11 and runs infinitely instead of recognizing the while condition, despite the fact that 11's rightChild would be null.

Comment: You need to do something with the return values of the recursive calls to `closest`.

Comment: Regardless to your question - 2 weird things in your code: 1. You're passing `difference` but override it immediately. why? 2. If you wanted your recursion to work, I guess you should `return closest (...)`, and not just call the function without return its value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should choose when to call recursion based on the condition you check, and return the value of that recursion. 
I only moved 2 lines that you wrote at the bottom to your if conditions.

And also you don't need to pass in the difference, because you are not using it's value:

```
public static int closest(Node<Integer, Person> n1, int smallest, int key, int key1) {
    while (n1 != null) {
        int difference = key - n1.key;
        if (smallest == 0) {
            smallest = difference;
            key1 = n1.key;
            return closest(n1.rightChild, smallest, key, key1);
        } else {
            if (difference < smallest) {
                smallest = difference;
                key1 = n1.key;
                return closest(n1.leftChild, smallest, key, key1);
            }
        }
    }

    return key1;
}
```

Update:

Actually I'm not sure if your code is even correct conceptually. I didn't try to compile or run it, but you should try to name your variables so they are more self explaining to make your code more readable. I don't see a reason for a while loop if you are doing recursion. Also, to find the closest number, you have to compare the absolute value of the distance. I believe you are trying to achieve something like this:

```
public static int closest(Node<Integer, Person> node, int distanceToTarget, int target, int result) {
    if (node != null) {
        int newDistance = target - node.key;

        if (Math.abs(newDistance) > Math.abs(distanceToTarget)) {
            // If previous result was closer
            return result;
        } else if (newDistance > 0) {
            return closest(node.rightChild, newDistance, target, node.key);
        } else if (newDistance < 0) {
            return closest(node.leftChild, newDistance, target, node.key);
        }
    }

    return result;
}
```